# Python selenium identify web element using custom attributes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, attributes, webdriver

I have the custom attribute called *upgrade-test="secondary-pull"* in the following script:

```
<section class="dvd-pull tech-pull-- secondary-pull--anonymous tech-pull--digital secondary-pull--dvd-ping tech-pull--minimise" upgrade-test="secondary-pull mktg-data-content" data-js="primary-pull" style="--primary-direct-d_user-bottom-pos:-290px;">
```

I wish to use this attribute to identify the element in question. I have tried the following, but unfortunately the script did not work:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//class[contains(@vlaue, 'secondary-pull')]")
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to know about how to identify and use `xpath`

Given the html
`<section class="dvd-pull tech-pull-- secondary-pull--anonymous tech-pull--digital secondary-pull--dvd-ping tech-pull--minimise" upgrade-test="secondary-pull" data-js="primary-pull" style="--primary-direct-d_user-bottom-pos:-290px;">`

xpath should be like

`//node[@attribute_name='attribute_value']`

in your case `xpath` should have been

```
//section[@upgrade-test='secondary-pull']
```

Ideally your python code should have been

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[@upgrade-test='secondary-pull']")
```

There can be many ways to do that. Take one more `xpath`

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@class,'secondary-pull')]")
```

Comment: Thank you @KunduK. You are right I really need to work on learning about XPATH, even though I am new to automation - No Exccuse. For now, I appreciate your help and your honest advice.

Comment: You can learn from following link : https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-writing-cheat-sheet-tutorial-examples/

Comment: @chauhany : SO is use for research purpose not for resolving OP query. I would appreciate, if you could post a separate question and your expected output.